# How can I convert a list to return a Json?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have the following code and need to retrieve faq type questions from a bd, how can I convert the list returned to a json, the following code presents: Object of type 'Question' is not JSON serializable

I'm using flask and Python3

```
@app.route("/faq/<question>")

@app.route("/faq/",defaults={"question":None})

def teste(question):
   r=Question.query.all()

   return jsonify(r)
```

Object of type 'Question' is not JSON serializable

Comment: looks like r is not a list.Its a object. you need to convert it to a list first.

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(r)`?

Comment: sure, print(r) = [<Question 'Aprovado'>, <Question 'Aprovado'>, <Question 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.'>, <Question 't is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.'>, <Question 'Pode basta agrupar pela ordem'>]

Comment: and print(type(r)) = list

Comment: Then it *is* a list; and the problem is the type of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains `Question` objects that aren't serializable as JSON. If you want the output to be a list of strings, you should use

```
jsonify(list(map(str, r)))
```

(This assumes that the question objects can be converted to string.)

Comment: Thanks soo much Bro, Its Work